# Visual Studio 2022 can't find Qt6.4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have installed VS2017+Qt5.9.2, and they works pretty well. Recently I want to try QHttpServer which has been added since Qt6.4.

I installed Qt with qt-unified-windows-x64-4.5.1-online.exe.

To go with the latest Qt, I installed the latest VS which is 2022.

I installed the Qt Addin / extension for the VS.

[image]

Now, I'm creating a solution (and a project) with them. I checked the Qt version is still in old one instead of the new one 6.4.

[image]

Do you have any idea to make VS2022 find the Qt6.4?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Actually you can manually specify the Qt6.4 path.

[image]

And even there is no httpserver module in the dialog, you can specify it in the settings manually.

[image]

It works well for me now.